# Excel VBA - hide path while saving file to another location

Tags: vba, excel

I have a nice, short macro that does a "save as" of an active workbook to a specified path. All works fine, however I would like to hide the prompt or at least the path that pops up ("uploading to C:/blabla/blabla/ location") - because I don't want the users to be able to see the path name or where the file is uploading.

I have tried *Application.DisplayAlerts = False* but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Do you have any tips on how to achieve this?

Thanks, 
Coco

Answer (score 0):

is it a message box or something else because a script like below does not give out a pop up.

```
Sub net()

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("D:\dave\abcd\Desktop\abcd.xlsx")
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like this - ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=("D:\dave\abcd\Desktop\") & XLSName & dt & " " & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False. Where XLSName carries the  specific name that the file should be saved as, and dt carries a date time prompt showing the date and time when it was saved. And a prompt does show up for this

Comment: Actually, the place where it's uploading is a Sharepoint - maybe that's why there's a prompt? Because it says "uploading to <path>" and visually it's a different prompt than the "standard" excel prompts