# Is there any option hide Saving Dialog box in Microsoft Office interop Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I set code for save excel using Microsoft Office interop Excel but when my excel file Save it's Display saving Dialog box like image. it's security issue because display save path

[image]

Code

```
excelWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\MyExcelTestTest.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false, false,
Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"it's security issue because display save path"_ - no it's not. Hiding a path is not a security measurement.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is for security, you can use an excel macro to not display the popup

Please check:[Excel VBA - hide path while saving file to another location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200594/excel-vba-hide-path-while-saving-file-to-another-location)